# Wireless connection always disabled in elementary OS 5.1 Hera

Tags: wifi, release-hera

I using elementary OS 5.1 Hera.
My pc wifi adapter is D-link dwa 123.

I didn't have this problem after installing Elementary os, but after rebooting, this problem occurred.

[image: Problem]

Comment: take look. there's something like that
https://askubuntu.com/questions/413027/how-to-make-a-d-link-dwa-123-wireless-n-150-work-on-ubuntu-13-10-saucy/413962

Comment: This problem is still here, now it is November 2020 and I just installed Here just today on my Laptop. I cannot use it normal because of this problem. Anyone got A solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem sometimes, disabling the wireless network using the button top right and endabling it again usually works for me.

Comment: Nah, It doesn't work for me

Comment: @Bo rislav Since Hera is installed it happens very often to me, I do like you, turn the wifi off in the upper panel and on again after a few seconds, but it lasts only a few minutes and then it happens again, and if I am streaming music or a movie it is really nerving. While it can be my crapy internet provider, on Juno (using same provider) it hardly ever happened. Is there a more permanent soltion than the off-on thing?

Comment: I see.. No I do not have a better solution, actually I do not have this problem very often, I may say on my system it was happening more often in Juno than in Hera.. I recommend you to file an issue to the developers team in github